# std::pair complains about incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

How to compile the following code?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A;

template<typename T>
struct B{
    T* p;

    B& operator=(B&&);
    B& operator=(T&&);
};

int main(){
    //typedef B<A> type;// fine
    typedef B<std::pair<A, A>> type;// error

    noexcept(std::declval<type&>() = std::declval<type>());

    return 0;
}
```

PS: Type B simulates the boost::recursive_wrapper which fails to compile for the same reason.

Comment: **17.6.4.8/2** In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: ... --if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component,
unless specifically allowed for that component.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The typedef, by itself, shouldn't instantiate `std::pair<A, A>`.

Comment: Is it an option to make `B` a template and `A` a template parameter?

Comment: @jxh A typedef is not a context that requires a complete type.

Comment: @5gon12eder I edit the code to use template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typedef itself isn't the problem. It's perfectly legal to write `struct foo; typedef std::pair<foo, foo> bar;`. The problem is with

```
noexcept(std::declval<type&>() = std::declval<type>());
```

This requires the compiler to perform overload resolution for `operator=`. As part of overload resolution it must look for possible conversions from `B&&` to `std::pair<A, A>&&`, and that requires instantiating `std::pair<A,A>` (§14.7.1 [temp.inst]/p6):

> A class template specialization is implicitly instantiated if the
>   class type is used in a context that requires a completely-defined
>   object type or if the completeness of the class type might affect the
>   semantics of the program. [ *Note*: In particular, if the semantics of
>   an expression depend on the member or base class lists of a class
>   template specialization, the class template specialization is
>   implicitly generated. For instance, deleting a pointer to class type
>   depends on whether or not the class declares a destructor, and
>   conversion between pointer to class types depends on the inheritance
>   relationship between the two classes involved. —*end note* ]

...and, by §17.6.4.8 [res.on.functions]/p2, this instantiation causes undefined behavior.

Although the compiler is not required to instantiate `std::pair<A, A>` in this context since the move assignment operator is an exact match (§14.7.1 [temp.inst]/p7):

> If the overload resolution process can determine the correct function
>   to call without instantiating a class template definition, it is
>   unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place.

Comment: I think you catch the point. So how to bypass the problem? You may study boost::recursive_wrapper directly.

Comment: @user1535111 I can't make any sense out of some of the compilers' behavior here. So [I've asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925551/gcc-and-clang-implicitly-instantiate-template-arguments-during-operator-overload).

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually put in the entire declaration of A before your use it in another declaration. A forward reference won't be enough.

Comment: The problem is sometimes it is impossible to do that. This is the value of boost::recursive_wrapper.