# gcc and clang implicitly instantiate template arguments during operator overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

Consider this code:

```
struct A; // incomplete type

template<class T>
struct D { T d; };

template <class T>
struct B { int * p = nullptr; };

int main() {
    B<D<A>> u, v;
    u = v;  // doesn't compile; complain that D<A>::d has incomplete type
    u.operator=(v); // compiles
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bee4448c4b33d91f). Since `u.operator=(v)` compiles but `u = v;` doesn't, somewhere during the overload resolution for the latter expression the compiler must have implicitly instantiated `D<A>` - but I don't see why that instantiation is required.

To make things more interesting, this code compiles:

```
struct A; // incomplete type

template<class T>
struct D; // undefined

template <class T>
struct B { int * p = nullptr; };

int main() {
    B<D<A>> u, v;
    u = v;
    u.operator=(v);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abdf8b03af21d782).

What's going on here? Why does `u = v;` cause the implicit instantiation of `D<A>` - a type that's nowhere used in the body of `B`'s definition - in the first case but not the second?

Comment: On Visual Studio 2013 it compiles, but gives runtime error. `Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'v' is being used without being initialized.` on `u = v;` on both tests.

Comment: @KugBuBu That's an unrelated issue. I added an initializer for `p` in the code just in case; nothing changed. (And VS's template engine is notoriously non-standard, so...)

Comment: Have you considered whether the lookup for the assignment-operator requires instantiating related types due to ADL? Classes that appear as template arguments are related as per [basic.lookup.argdep]/2

Comment: (It doesn't make much sense for assignment, as it can only be implemented as a member function, though. I'm not sure however how the implementers interpret the algorithm in [over.match.oper]/3; maybe they always perform this lookup, even if there can be no non-member results.)

Comment: [A very contrived example for operators with non-member candidates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a393a0adaf6d063)

Comment: @T.C. I added my test because it is more confusing that VS-compiler could compile incomplete type. (The second test is somehow reasonable, because `A` isn't used, you don't need to know it's size)

Comment: @dyp I think you are right about ADL and that the implementation might be instantiating the template regardless of whether `operator =` can be a nonmember. That doesn't quite explain why it doesn't attempt to instantiate `D<A>` (and fail) in the second example, though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The entire point of the matter is [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) kicking in:

N3797 - [basic.lookup.argdep]

> When the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2) is an unqualified-id, other namespaces not considered
>   during the usual unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched, and in those namespaces, namespace-scope
>   friend function or function template declarations (11.3) not otherwise visible may be found.

following:

> For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a
>   set of zero or more associated classes to be considered. [...] The sets of
>   namespaces and classes are determined in the following way:
>
> - If T is a class type [..] its associated classes are: ...
>     furthemore if T is a class template specialization its associated namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and classes associated with the
>     types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters

`D<A>` is an associated class and therefore in the list waiting for its turn.

Now for the interesting part [temp.inst]/1

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), 
>   the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated [...] **when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program**

One could think that the completeness of the type `D<A>` doesn't affect at all the semantic of that program, however [basic.lookup.argdep]/4 says:

> When considering an associated namespace, the lookup is the same as the lookup performed when the associated namespace is used as a qualifier (3.4.3.2)
>   except that:
>
> [...]
>   Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates declared in associated classes are visible within their respective 
>   namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup (11.3)

i.e. the completeness of the class type **actually affects** friends declarations -> the completeness of the class type therefore affects the semantics of the program.
That is also the reason why your second sample works.

**TL;DR** `D<A>` is instantiated.

The last interesting point regards why ADL starts in the first place for

```
u = v; // Triggers ADL
u.operator=(v); // Doesn't trigger ADL
```

§13.3.1.2/2 dictates that there can be no non-member `operator=` (other than the built-in ones). Join this to [over.match.oper]/2:

> The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified lookup of operator@ in the context
>   of the expression according to the usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2)
>   except that all member functions are ignored.

and the logical conclusion is: there's no point in performing the ADL lookup if there's no non-member form in table 11. However [temp.inst]p7 relaxes this:

> If the overload resolution process can determine the correct function to call without instantiating a class template definition, it is unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place.

and that's the reason why clang triggered the entire `ADL -> implicit instantiation` process in the first place.

Starting from [r218330](https://www.mail-archive.com/cfe-commits@cs.uiuc.edu/msg106405.html) (at the time of writing this, it has been committed a few minutes ago) this behavior was changed not to perform ADL for `operator=` at all.

---

**References**

- [r218330](https://www.mail-archive.com/cfe-commits@cs.uiuc.edu/msg106405.html)
- [clang sources](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang) / *Sema* module
- [cfe-dev](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/ADL-causing-implicit-template-class-instantiation-failure-td4041705.html)
- [N3797](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf)

Thanks to Richard Smith and David Blaikie for helping me figuring this out.

Comment: Looks like there are two separate questions - 1) is the compiler required/allowed to instantiate `D<A>` for `operator=`? (I think we all agree that ADL requires instantiation for operators that can be non-members.) 2) In cases where `D<A>` is required to be instantiated (e.g., binary `operator-`) why does the second example [compile at all](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14198a7afbdead46)? Implicitly instantiating a template that's declared but not defined should render the program ill-formed ([temp.inst]/p8).

Comment: Clang definitely was for 1) before r218330. As for 2) its completeness doesn't affect program's semantic

Comment: Why not? Either proper ADL (in cases where the operator can be a non-member, at least) requires instantiation of `D<A>` or it doesn't. You can't have it both ways. (In the example linked in my comment, `B::operator -` isn't the best theoretically possible match for the expression `u - v` either, so [temp.inst]/p7 can't apply.)

Comment: it does for that definition, but the point here is whether ADL should be performed for this code or not.

Comment: So the short of it is 1) both versions of the code that uses the assignment operator should compile and shouldn't instantiate `D<A>`, with the standardese here being possibly defective/unclear and 2) if the code's modified to use `operator -` instead (with an appropriate overload in `B`'s definition) then neither version should compile, because ADL requires `D<A>`'s instantiation - and clang (and gcc)'s compiling the modified second version is a bug?

Comment: All correct (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37a510ca0ccd112b), although in this case there's no bug, it is a well-defined behavior

Comment: Aha, so I was on the right track. Thanks for being more persistent than me and checking this with the clang devs.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I think in Visual Studio 2013 code should look like(without = nullptr):

```
  struct A; // incomplete type

  template<class T>
  struct D { T d; };

  template <class T>
  struct B { int * p; };

  int void_main() {
    B<D<A>> u, v;
    u = v;          //  compiles
    u.operator=(v); // compiles
    return 0;
    }
```

In this case it should compile well just because incomplete types can be used for specific template class specialization usage.

As for the run-time error - the variable v used without initialization - it's correct - struct B does not have any constructor => B::p is not initialized and could contain garbage.